# c++ std::sort a std::vector using a function return value

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector

I have a `Policy` class with the following function:

```
double Policy::meanResponse();
```

Suppose I have a vector of `Policy` objects (`myPolicies`) that I wish to sort, and I wish to sort based on the value of `Policy::meanResponse()`.  I have tried the following:

```
bool compare_by_function(const Policy& p1, const Policy& p2)
{
    return ( p1.meanResponse() < p2.meanResponse() );
}

sort(myPolicies.begin(), myPolicies.end(), compare_by_function);
```

But I get the error:

> "error: passing 'const Policy' as 'this' argument of 'double Policy::meanResponse()' discards qualifers"

**Can someone please explain how to correctly sort in this case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try changing meanResponse to const?

```
double Policy::meanResponse()const;
```

Since you are passing the Policy objects to the compare function with const reference you can't call non-const methods on them.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-member-fns.html

Comment: No, not yet I haven't.  What is the effect of adding `const` after the parentheses of the function?  I've never done that before.

Comment: It marks your method as constant, which means you are not changing the  state of the object in that method.